# how to setup connection between PC and android devices through wifi

Tags: android, windows, wifi, ubuntu-11.10

i am developing android application which runs in my pc and connects to different android devices through wify and communicate with them,how i setup wifi connection for this purpose,is it possible to connect more devices to my pc through wifi,I need to setup connection in ubutu11.10 or windows 7

Comment: Your use of the word "connection" is very vague. A lot of it depends on the type of information you want to pass. I would recommend you provide more information about the specifics of the app.

Comment: in my application i need to connect my pc and multiple android devices through wifi,and my pc have to send some data to each device connected to the PC simultaneously,no need of internet connection,only i want to create network connection and tcp/udp(if possible) data transfer

Answer (score 5):

Your question is vague and open to a lot of potentially "correct" answers. First of all, the whole wifi v.s. internet part is irrelevant, you just want to communicate from your Android devices to your pc over the network.

The term to look for is `sockets`. What you do is listen to particular port on the PC (the "server"). You'll have to open up the relevant ports in the firewall.

You then write an android app that communicates with this server, see [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) for a proper introduction.

There is no problem using a single socket (ip address + port) to connect with multiple devices, as long as your protocol includes a way for each client to identify itself.

...

That said, you can also do all of this at a higher level, running a SOAP/JSON-based client/server scheme (as opposed to writing your own socket-based protocol). See http://wiebe-elsinga.com/blog/?p=405 for an example.

What is the most appropriate choice depends on your exact requirements (performance, deployment) and your level of experience.

Comment: how i setup wifi connection for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at establishing an ADB connection to a device try ADB wireless http://www.helloandroid.com/content/connect-your-android-phone-adb-wireless

You will need to root your device for this to work