# Easiest way to get information from Android to PC via WIFI?

Tags: android, windows, wifi, communication

What is the easiest way to get information from Andriod to PC via WIFI?
I'm doing an app that receives SMS messages. I want to save the information in a database on a Windows computer, right after the messages have been received.

I've tried:
HttpPost (could not get AsyncTask to work)
JDBC (just does not work)
... and even WebView (could not get findViewById work - seems buggy).

I can start the internal web browser on an external link by code, so it's not a network problem.

If there is a better and easier way please give a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have checked the other related questions. You can code a client and server application for your android device and pc. See [wireless connection between mobile device and pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037482/wireless-connection-between-mobile-device-and-pc) for detaield answer.

You can use `sockets` and listen on a particular port on your PC and then with app you can communicate with it. See [how to setup connection between PC and android devices through wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548539/how-to-setup-connection-between-pc-and-android-devices-through-wifi) . These questions would help you to get what you want.

If you have any specific problem with your implementation, you may follow up with code sniplet and your problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting up a TCP server on the device and then sending to the pc with the pc as a client?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I looked at the server client solution, but it is not so simple. Will look at the links from Shobhit Puri.
Believe me - I've been looking, reading and testing a lot.

Comment: Having looked at the suggestions you have provided, but think they are too difficult. I solve this by instead start the internal web browser, and makes the interface in HTML.
Thanks for your replies.
Intent browser = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse (strURL));
startup activity (browser);